# Flask-jwt-extended doesn't support required claims?

Tags: flask, flask-jwt, flask-jwt-extended

I'm using flask-jwt-extended over flask-jwt but there doesn't seem to be support for requiring claims.

Is this something I have to implement myself in a new identity function and if so how do I override the existing functionality in flask-jwt-extended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author here. For what it's worth, flask-jwt doesn't support requiring claims either (even though it says it does). https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-jwt/issues/98

EDIT:
This is now available in flask-jwt-extended. https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-extended/issues/64#issuecomment-318800617

Cheers